# Why an LWP (Light Weight Process) is required for each concurrent system call in many to many thread model?

Tags: multithreading

A **LWP** is a data structure placed between user thread and kernel thread, and appears as a virtual processor to user thread library. **So, the minimum number of LWP required in many to many model of threading is the number of concurrent blocking system calls.**

Please explain why is it so?

Comment: "A LWP is a data structure placed between user thread and kernel thread": This all is confusing from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Lightweight Process is (in Unix and Unix-like) a process that runs in user space over a single kernel thread and shares its address space and resources with other LWPs of the same user process.

A system call is an invocation of kernel functionality from user space. When a user process performs a system call, the call is handled by the LWP associated with the user process/thread and gets **blocked while the call is handled** down in the kernel (through the kernel thread associated with the LWP) and when the call is solved, the kernel thread and LWP are free again.

That is why the *minimum* number of LWPs required in a many to many threading model is the amount of concurrent **blocking** system calls, because blocking system calls and LWPs are 1:1 related (The LWP cannot do any other task when engaged by a blocking system call from the user thread)